# MS SQL: Select rows whose many date columns are withing range if not null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have what I think is a rather complex query to do, but havent reached a solution, and I would like to know if it is possible to do it just by a complex query or I need to postprocess the result.

I have a budgets table, with a budget code, and several dates like enterDate, deliveryDate, desiredDeliveryDate, shippingDate, etc.

Some of the dates can be null. Others may be set.

I need a query to return the rows of those budgets whose any of the dates is in a date range interval. But I don't want to consider dates that are null values. To be more specific, I'll try to put an example.

```
BudgetID  |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |  D5  | 
a         | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
b         | NULL |  IR  |  OR  |  OR  |
c         | NULL | NULL | NULL |  IR  |
d         |  OR  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
```

NULL of course means that value is null.
IR means that date is IN RANGE.
OR meands that date is OUT RANGE.

The result should be the following:

```
BudgetID  |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |  D5  | 
b         | NULL |  IR  |  OR  |  OR  |
c         | NULL | NULL | NULL |  IR  |
```

Budget a does not match, as all date columns are NULL.
Budget b does match, because there is at least one NOT NULL Date within range.
Budget c does mate because of the same reason of avobe.
Budget d does not match as the all the NOT NULL Date are out range.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've thought of a possible solution given the nature of the creation of the query. As I know the range beforehand and I construct the query parametrically using string.Format in C#, I've decided to use ISNULL with a date value outside the range for each DATE column before comparing with the range. That would make NULL dates fail always.

Comment: Could you provide your table structure?

Comment: It is incredibly big. Better don't see any table structure in our DB, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT BudgetId, D1, D2, D4, D4, D5
FROM YourTable
WHERE  ISNULL(D1, DATEADD(DD, 1, @max)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
    OR ISNULL(D2, DATEADD(DD, 1, @max)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
    OR ISNULL(D3, DATEADD(DD, 1, @max)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
    OR ISNULL(D4, DATEADD(DD, 1, @max)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
    OR ISNULL(D5, DATEADD(DD, 1, @max)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
```

Comment: This is was I finally implemented, as I explained in my edited post. But with a little add, because some times the min date is OPEN, and sometimes the max date is open.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on distribution of NULL within those four DT columns and/or on selectivity of those conditions I would use one of bellow queries:

```
SELECT  b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
WHERE   b.D1 BETWEEN @a AND @b
OR      b.D2 BETWEEN @a AND @b
OR      b.D3 BETWEEN @a AND @b
OR      b.D4 BETWEEN @a AND @b
```

-- or

```
SELECT  DISTINCT b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT D1 WHERE D1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT D2 WHERE D2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT D3 WHERE D3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT D4 WHERE D4 IS NOT NULL
) ca (AllDt)
WHERE ca.AllDt BETWEEN @a AND @b
```

-- or

```
SELECT  b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
WHERE   b.D1 BETWEEN @a AND @b
UNION -- UNION removes duplicated values
SELECT  b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
WHERE   b.D2 BETWEEN @a AND @b
UNION 
SELECT  b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
WHERE   b.D3 BETWEEN @a AND @b
UNION 
SELECT  b.BudgetID 
FROM    dbo.Budget b
WHERE   b.D4 BETWEEN @a AND @b
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for your case..

```
CREATE TABLE #temp   (BudgetID  VARCHAR(3),  D1 DATETIME ,  D2 DATETIME ,  D3 DATETIME ,  D5 DATETIME ) 
INSERT #temp (BudgetID  ,  D1  ,  D2  ,  D3  ,  D5  ) 
VALUES
('a' , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL ),
('b' , NULL , 'Apr 01 2016 12:00:00:000AM',  'May 30 2016 12:00:00:000AM', 'Jun 10 2016 12:00:00:000AM' ),
('c' , NULL , NULL , NULL , 'Apr 15 2016 12:00:00:000AM' ),
('d' ,  'Jan 30 2016 12:00:00:000AM', NULL , NULL , NULL )
/*INSERT #temp (BudgetID  ,  D1  ,  D2  ,  D3  ,  D5  ) 
VALUES('e' , 'Apr 30 2016 12:00:00:000AM' , 'Apr 10 2016 12:00:00:000AM' , NULL , NULL )*/
SELECT BudgetID,D1 as DATE FROM (
select BudgetID,D1 from #temp
UNION
select BudgetID,D2 from #temp
UNION
select BudgetID,D3 from #temp
UNION 
select BudgetID,D5 from #temp
)a WHERE a.D1 between '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30' 
--(OR)
SELECT BudgetID,ColumnName,DATES
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY (BudgetID) ) Row_NO,BudgetID , D1  ,  D2  ,  D3  ,  D5    
FROM #TEMP
) AS a
UNPIVOT
(DATES FOR ColumnName IN ( D1  ,  D2  ,  D3  ,  D5  )) AS up
WHERE DATES between '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
```

But need to see one more scenario...if the same row has multiple dates and the dates are within the given range then it will return multiple rows(to see this scenario just uncomment and `insert` budjetID 'e' row into the temp table).
If your requirement is just finding the budgetID then just select `distinct budgetID` only.